# limit dragging property of a div inside inside another div?

Tags: jquery

please help me to 
limit dragging property of a div inside inside another div
example 
http://galtech.org/testing/drag.php
i need dragg the red div only inside the blue div pls help me
i am using jQuery draggble

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable();
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable({ containment: 'parent' });
  });
  </script>
```

suppose blue div is parent

[docs here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#option-containment)

Comment: please help me to fix this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967315/jquery-draggble-has-a-problem-on-dragging